# Old files not showing up on PC. Suggestions for Workarounds?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, data-transfer, mtp

I'm trying to transfer files from one phone to another. I connected both of them to my computer with usb. However, files that are older than 6/15/17 do not show up on the computer. I can see them in my file manager app, but not on PC.

Comment: Try restarting PC

Answer (score 0):

You can use Airdroid to transfer files over local WiFi connection or use adb to pull all files.

1. Install adb on your PC
2. Turn on USB debugging from Developer settings
3. Use `adb pull` command to copy everything